# Battery size calculation

Tags: batteries, capacitor

I am designing a battery run device and would like to check with you if my calculations are correct. To make it simple, the battery will be used to charge repeatedly a capacitor:

Capacitor: 40uF @ 300V

Repetition rate: 1Hz

My calculations are:

To charge the cap to 300V, I will need 40uF x 300V = 12m Coulomb.
To charge the cap repeatedly at 1Hz for 1 hour, I will need 12mC x 3600/h = 43.2C/h.
A 1000mAh battery is a 3600 Coulomb energy source.
Using this battery I will be able to run the device for 3600C/43.28C/h = 83.3 hours?

Thank you

Comment: There is something important between the battery and the capacitor, but you haven't told us anything about it. What is the efficiency of your boost converter? What is the end voltage of your battery corresponding to the 1000mAh rating?

Comment: Are you assuming a 300V 1000mAh battery?  If not, your calculations need re-thinking.

Comment: a 3600 Coulmb energy source is nonsensical. A 3600 coulomb charge source makes sense.

Comment: *A 1000mAh battery is a 3600 Coulomb energy source* Hmm, I'd swear that my 1.2 V, 1000 mAh NiMh battery contains **way less** energy than my 14 V, 1000 mAh Li-Ion laptop battery. Also a Coulomb is just a bunch of electrons (or lack of electrons) sitting there, by themselves they have no energy (that I can use anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 40uF capacitor charged to 300v requires \$0.5CV^2\$ = 1.8Joules of energy. Once per second, that's 1.8W, assuming no losses.

Charging a high voltage capacitor is best done from a variable voltage step-up current source, for which a flyback boost converter is a perfect fit. This will obviously have some losses, so we'll need more than 1.8 watts.

If you had a 1000mAh LiPo battery, at a nominal 3.7v, that would store 3600*3.7 = 13320 Joules. This would power a 1.8 watt load for 13320/1.8 = 7400s = about 2 hours. Allowing for losses, you might hope for more than one hour.

If the battery had a different voltage, then the energy capacity sums would be different. With a different, perhaps lossier method of charging the capacitor, the loss estimates would be different.

Comment: Ok, this makes more sense. I forgot to include under ideal conditions, without losses. Thank you.